# Probability of Winning a Game Question

Tags: probability

An urn has 9 white balls and 11 black balls. You draw a ball from the urn, note its color, and put it back in the urn. If it is white, you win 5 cents from your opponent; if black, you lose 5 cents to your opponent. You have a dollar to gamble with and your opponent has 50cents. If you keep on playing until one of you loses all his money, what is the probability that you will lose your dollar?

Ok, is there any advice on how to approach this problem? I know that I can only lose on the 20th draw, the 22nd draw, the 24th draw...etc... and that I need to lose the last 2 draws.

I can also create the probabilities for the first couple scenarios... but I don't know how to create a general formula that can get me the total probability.

Comment: You may want to search online about "Gambler's Ruin", which is essentially what your problem is. Here is the Wikipedia page on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "money" as introduced in the question, I would think of the problem in terms of "points" to make it easier.

The problem is equivalent to saying that you start of at $20$ points. White ball gives $+1$ point and black ball gives $-1$ point. You win when you reach $30$ points and you lose when you hit $0$ points.

Let $p_n$ be the probability that you win given that you currently have $n$ points. i.e. we would like to find the value of $p_{20}$.

But first, let's suppose we currently have $n$ points and condition on the first ball being drawn in this state. By the law of total probability, we have

$$p_n = (p_n|\text{ first draw is white}) \cdot \Bbb P(\text{first draw is white}) \\ \qquad \qquad + (p_n|\text{ first draw is black}) \cdot \Bbb P(\text{first draw is black})$$

If we currently have $n$ points and then we draw a white ball, then we would have $n+1$ points, and then the probability of winning would at that point be $p_{n+1}$ (as though we had started with $n+1$ points).

Similarly, if we currently have $n$ points and then we draw a black ball, the probability of winning becomes $p_{n-1}$.

The probability of drawing a white ball is $\frac{9}{20}$ and that of drawing a black ball is $\frac{11}{20}$. So the above formula becomes

$$p_n = \frac{9}{20}p_{n+1} + \frac{11}{20}p_{n-1}$$

This is true for all $n = 1,\dots,29$.

If we currently have $0$ points then we have already lost, so $p_0 = 0$. Similarly, if we currently have $30$ points then we have already won, so $p_{30} = 1$.

All that's left now is to solve the recurrence relation

$$p_n = \frac{9}{20}p_{n+1} + \frac{11}{20}p_{n-1} \qquad \qquad p_0 = 0 \qquad p_{30} = 1$$

The solution is found to be

$$p_n = \frac{\big(\frac{11}{9}\big)^n-1}{\big(\frac{11}{9}\big)^{30}-1}$$

In particular,

$$p_{20} = \frac{\big(\frac{11}{9}\big)^{20}-1}{\big(\frac{11}{9}\big)^{30}-1} = 0.132...$$